# Is there a way to convert a Cobertura XML into an HTML report?

Tags: code-coverage, cobertura

I have a XML file generated in a test. Is there a way to convert it to a HTML report ala Jenkins?

Comment: An XSLT transformation?

Answer (score 7):

[pycobertura](https://pypi.org/project/pycobertura/) can take `coverage.xml` and convert it into reasonable-looking HTML. I'm using it with some Erlang source code right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ant, you can use (notice 'format="**html**"'):

```
<cob:cobertura-report format="html" datafile="${cobertura.ser.file}" destdir="${todir}">
     <fileset dir="${srcdir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
</cob:cobertura-report>
```

With a maven pom, refer to: [the manual](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/examples/report-formats.html), e.g.:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
     <formats>
       <format>html</format>
       <!-- format>xml</format -->
     </formats>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With a command-line script, refer to [the manual](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#reporting) too, e.g.:

```
cobertura-report.bat --format html --datafile C:\MyProject\build\cobertura.ser --destination C:\MyProject\reports\coverage C:\MyProject\src
```

Comment: What if the xml file is from lcov-to-cobertura or such?

Comment: I would look into this python-based [specific-purpose tool](http://eriwen.github.io/lcov-to-cobertura-xml/) though I have not used it myself.

Comment: I'm already using hat to create the cobertura.xml from gcov tests - what I need is a way to generate the HTML reports from the cobertura.xml file.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I misread the question. I gave .ser->html, you're asking xml->html. I can't find anything for that, nor the reverse engineering of the xml file into .ser (xml->.ser)